# Maximum length on a textarea in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, textarea

I tried applying the `:maxlenght` => 40 on a [textarea](http://www.w3schools.com/TAGS/tag_textarea.asp) on my form.
But it didn't work out.
Can we have a length limit on a textarea?

The code for text area is

```
<%= f.text_area :data,
                :rows => 2,
                :cols => 60 ,
                :maxlength => 140,
                :autocomplete => :off,
                :class => "textareabytes" %>
```

Answer (score 13):

Just like [Rahul](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/886352/max-length-on-a-textarea-in-ruby-on-rails/886363#886363) said, there's no `maxlength` attribute for `textarea` in HTML. Only `text` `input`'s have that.

The thing you need to remember, is that RoR's `text_area` function (and all of RoR's HTML-generator functions) accept any argument you'll give them. If they don't recognized the parameter, then the'll just convert it to HTML.

```
<%=f.text_area :data, :hellothere => "hello to you too"%>
```

Will output this HTML:

```
<textarea name="data" hellothere="hello to you too"></textarea>
```

I know it's hard to remember, but Ruby on Rails isn't magic, it just does a lot of things for you. The trick is to know how it does them, so you can understand why they work, and how to fix them when they don't!

Comment: There is a `maxlength` attribute for `textarea`since HTML5. Unfortunately, it is not supported in IE prior to 10. See MDN for [full details](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/textarea).

Comment: +1 for "I know It's hard to remember, but Ruby on Rails isn't magic-"

Comment: Sources on maxlength for HTML5:
http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_textarea_maxlength.asp
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/textarea#Attributes

Comment: I don't understand. According to what you say, the `<textarea maxlength="50"></textarea>` should be there then. Because once it is there on the client side, it works (at least in latest Chrome). But in my case it is not rendered.

Answer (score 4):

Could it be due to a typo?

":**maxlenght** => 40 " in your post is misspelt.

**EDIT:**

I didn't read your post carefully. I think there is no maxlength attribute for textarea in HTML. You will have to handle it in JavaScript. There is more information in "[MaxLength on a Textarea](http://blog.offbeatmammal.com/post/2006/10/26/MaxLength-on-a-Textarea.aspx)".

Comment: Im sorry 
actually Its correct in the code 
i spelt it wrong here

Comment: Thnx buddy
since no other go .....i wrote a javascript function to implement this....

Answer (score 1):

Not strictly what you're after of course, but, you can always put a:

```
validates_length_of :data, max: 40
```

on your model.  Won't stop the textarea size of course :)

Comment: Right approach even using maxlength tag.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the maxlength attribute. It is new for the  tag in HTML5. It should work nowadays.

Comment: You right! It works as well in Firefox, Chrome and Opera on Ubuntu in 2021! \o/