# No route matches [POST] "/account/new"

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to create a new account. but for some reason I'm getting this error when trying to submit the form `No route matches [POST] "/account/new"`. Here is my form_for:

```
<%= form_for @account, url: new_account_path, html: { method: :post }  do |form| %>
```

### ROUTES

```
account_index GET    /account(.:format)                                      account#index
                                  POST   /account(.:format)                                      account#create
                      new_account GET    /account/new(.:format)                                  account#new
                     edit_account GET    /account/:id/edit(.:format)                             account#edit
                          account GET    /account/:id(.:format)                                  account#show
                                  PATCH  /account/:id(.:format)                                  account#update
                                  PUT    /account/:id(.:format)                                  account#update
                                  DELETE /account/:id(.:format)                                  account#destroy
```

### ROUTES.RB

```
resources :account
```

### ACCOUNT CONTROLLER:

```
class AccountController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @account = Account.new
  end

  def create
    binding.pry
    interactor = CreateAccount.call(
      params: account_params,
      user: current_user
    )

    if interactor.success?
      redirect_to pages_dashboard_path
    else
      render :new
    end
  end

  private

  def account_params
    params.require(:account).permit(:name)
  end
end
```

### NEW.HTML.ERB

```
<div class="plans">
  <h1>New Account Plan</h1>

  <%= form_for @account, url: new_account_path, html: { method: :post }  do |form| %>
    <div class="plans__trial">
      <h3>Trial</h3>
      <p>1 Worker</p>
      <p>1 Assignment</p>

      <p class="price">Price: Free</p>

      <label>
        <%= form.submit "Select", name: "trial", class: "button" %>
      </label>
    </div>

    <div class="plans__tier-1">
      <h3>Tier 1</h3>
      <p>Unlimited Workers</p>
      <p>Unlimited Assignments</p>

      <p class="price">Price: $9.00</p>

      <label>
        <input type="radio" required  />
        <a href="" class="button">Select</a>
      </label>
    </div>

    <div class="cc-fields">
      <%= render partial: "shared/cc-fields" %>
    </div>
    <%= form.submit name: "tier_1" %>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

What am I doing wrong. Should it hit the create action? It's not currently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `form_for` line to just this, rails will automatically handle the routing if you follow Convention Over Configuration.

```
<%= form_for @account do |form| %>
```

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

It's right in your routes.

You're `POST`ing to the `NEW` route.  That doesn't work.  New is where you render a form for users to enter data.  Create is the action that will accept that data posted to it.

So change this:

```
<%= form_for @account, url: new_account_path, html: { method: :post }  do |form| %>
```

To this:

```
<%= form_for @account, url: account_path, html: { method: :post }  do |form| %>
```

Simplified:

```
<%= form_for @account do |form| %>
```

As long as your @account is a Account.new, which it is, it should work.

Comment: I get this error with that code `No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"account"} missing required keys: [:id]`

Comment: Now I get this error `undefined method `accounts_path' for #<#<Class:0x007fa9de271b60>:0x007fa9e4e1f5b0>`

Comment: remove the s from the path.  should be account_path

Answer (score 0):

Try change this code in routes.rb
`resources :account`
to:
`resources :accounts`
then you can use this code
`<%= form_for @account, url: new_account_path, html: { method: :post }  do |form| %>`

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue. I tried all the answers on similar posts and nothing worked including the ones above.

I even deleted the app and repeated the process and got stuck on the same issue.

After much frustration, I realised it had to do with the **text_area** field. In each case, I had copied random text from a web page into the body text field which was throwing the error. I knew this because I decided to type random text instead and voila! It worked on submission.

There was nothing wrong all the while. Since the [Ruby text_area attribute has no limit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/886352/maximum-length-on-a-textarea-in-ruby-on-rails), I guess it has to be with the characters I was copying messing with the code in the background since it converts what it does not understand to HTML as stated here.

This is my own particular case and I thought I should share.